# Python-pptx how to change text color of a cell in a table?

Tags: python-pptx

I am trying to change font color of cells in a table in powerpoint using python. I went through multiple sources and got other pieces like changing fill color to work.

I tried -

```
cell.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.color.rgb = RGBColor(80,80,0)
```

But nothing happens while the code runs without error. Any ideas of what can be happening here?

Comment: Possibly, paragraph contains multiple runs with different font settings, try to set the font color for each run separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cell.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.fill.solid()
cell.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(80,80,0)
```